# pandas adding a column via filtering the DataFrame based on values of current row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a case where I want to add a new column dependent on values that I obtain through filtering the DataFrame based on the current row. For example:

```
    date        happy   user
0   2017-05-01  True    user1
1   2017-05-02  True    user1
2   2017-05-03  False   user1
3   2017-05-04  True    user1
4   2017-05-01  False   user2
5   2017-05-02  True    user2
```

I want to add a column previous_days_happy that works out for each user on how many days before the current day they were happy. So here the output would be:

```
    date        happy   user    prev_happy_days
0   2017-05-01  True    user1   0
1   2017-05-02  True    user1   1
2   2017-05-03  False   user1   2
3   2017-05-04  True    user1   2
4   2017-05-01  False   user2   0
5   2017-05-02  True    user2   0
```

My research only finds me examples of adding a column based on the values in the current row. But here I want to take the values of the current row and use them to filter the DataFrame and calculate a value.

Regular filtering like:

```
df[df['userid'] < 1000]
```

doesn't help because the value to filter by is not constant, but rather dependent on the row.

I have also tried variations on groupby, with transforms to no avail, and I think that this is because a transform only takes in a Series, not a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data within each group is sorted by date:

```
df['prev_happy_days'] = df.groupby('user')['happy'].cumsum().astype(int)
```

Will return:

```
         date  happy   user  prev_happy_days
0  2017-05-01   True  user1                1
1  2017-05-02   True  user1                2
2  2017-05-03  False  user1                2
3  2017-05-04   True  user1                3
4  2017-05-01  False  user2                0
5  2017-05-02   True  user2                1
```

Comment: Thanks. And if the data is not sorted by date, we can just do `df.sort_values('date')`. 
Follow up: if I only want to look at the past week for the user, how do I modify this? (I know, the specific example I gave is a bad example with the dates provided).

Comment: Isn't the expected output and the output provided by this solution different?

Comment: @Satyadev agreed but I thought the desired output was not consistent, maybe OP can confirm...

Comment: You can try rolling functions, either [applied to groups](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html) directly or via [time-aware rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#time-aware-rolling).

Comment: @Satyadev there was an inconsistency between my question and the example output. I edited the question to be more correct. 
After using the code in the answer, I can add a line to convert the column to exactly what I desire.